# How to set style display of an html element in a selenium test?

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, styles

I get an element like

```
cv_upload = driver.find_element_by_id('id_cv_upload')
```

So I want to set its display as inline in python itself.**is it possible with python to set the display.**
I tried

```
cv_upload.style.display = "inline"
```

which is showing me error.
**One way** which is getting into my mind is to use Jquery to change the display and then execute it using `driver.execute` but unfortunately I am not getting the right syntax to do this. Let me know how to do this (The syntax.) Thanks.

Comment: seeing the error might be quite useful

Comment: What the frack is `driver` and `find_element_by_id` ?

Comment: driver = Webdriver.Firefox() selenium web driver

Comment: @NIleshSharma - got confused by jQuery, did'nt see it was python, strange question ?

Comment: I am asking for two solutions, One is it possible with python to set the display. Second with JQuery it is possible to do so but then how can I execute my JQuery in python program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally find out the way to set display of an element.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('id_cv_upload').style.display='block';")
```

basically using `driver.execute_script` I am executing a java script for setting the style of an element.

Comment: a java script? Like an applet, or what?

Answer (score 47):

since you marked jQuery - You can use the [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to set/get css attributes

```
$('#id_cv_upload').css('display','inline');
```

Comment: How can I execute in python program  ?

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer in the context of the question, which is selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box').css(
{
  background: "#FF0000",
  "box-shadow": "1px 1px 5px 5px red",
  width: "100px",
  height: "100px",
  display: "block"
}
);
```

[BSI.id().setStyle() vs jQuery.css() vs. native DOM](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-native-dom/13)

Answer (score 0):

In case your element doesn't have ID, you can do same using css

in python:

```
 driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('yourCSSLocatorGoesHere').style.display='block';")
```

in Java:

```
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();   
    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('yourCSSLocatorGoesHere').style.display='block';")
```